# Help with a first week level calculus question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

- This is part of my homework BUT I had already "solved" this as we only submit final answers, and I know how to find the solution, what I am not able to do is prove it using the tools I was taught, and such a proof is not part of my homework, although I believe its expected of me *

The question is:
How can I formally prove that the supremum of the following set is indeed 8/3 WITHOUT USING LIMITS?
{8n/(3n+1) | n∈N}

Notice that I am not yet allowed to use limits, and the way I believe I am supposed to be solving this is by showing that a limit of 4/3-ε has to be lesser than or equal to a member of the set, which I tried to do by assuming it is greater than all members of the set and looking for a contradiction. The problem is that I am not able to get rid of n and therefore I cant reach a contradiction as there seems to be a matching epsilon for whatever N is and no contradiction can be achieved.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Hi, there are two questions here. I would recommend breaking this up into two separate questions; One about the problem and one about the axiom.

Comment: OK thanks, I removed the second question and will post it separately

Comment: This seems like a tough one.  You can re-write $\displaystyle \frac{8n}{3n+1} = \frac{8n + (8/3)}{3n + 1} - \frac{(8/3)}{3n + 1} = (8/3) - \frac{8}{9n +3}$.  Then, you are supposed to reason that as $\displaystyle n \to \infty, \frac{8}{9n+3}$ *approaches zero from above*.  However, I don't see how you can conclude that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{8}{9n + 3} = 0$, without some consideration of limits, presumably involving the corresponding $\epsilon,\delta$ definition.  ...see next comment

Comment: Given that, you could (instead) apply the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition directly to the initial fraction $\displaystyle \frac{8n}{3n+1},~$ so I don't see how my approach has helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to show that $8/3$ is $an$ upper bound. To show it is the $least$ upper bound, you show that any $x<8/3$ is $not$ an upper bound.

By contradiction suppose  $x<8/3$ and $x$ is an upper bound. Then for all $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $8n/(3n+1)\le x<8/3.$ This implies that $y=8/3-x$ satisfies  $$(\bullet)\quad 0<y\le 8/3-8n/(3n+1)=8/(9n+3)<1/n$$ for every $n\in \Bbb N.$

The $definition$ of $\Bbb R$ implies that if $0<1/y\in \Bbb R$ then $0<1/y<n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ and hence $y>1/n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N,$ contradicting $(\bullet)$.

Note: I am assuming, as usual, that we are working within $\Bbb R.$ It is possible to extend $\Bbb R$ to a larger ordered field $\Bbb R^*$ in which all the standard rules for $+,\times,$ and $<$ still apply, but where there are members that are larger than every member of $\Bbb N.$ And their reciprocals will be positive but less than any positive member of $\Bbb R.$ But we lose something: $\Bbb R^*$ will not have the $lub$ property; in particular $\{8n/(3n+1):n\in\Bbb N\}$ has $no$ lub in $\Bbb R^*.$  This makes $\Bbb R^*$ unpopular and you are unlikely to meet it in introductory calculus. But I want to emphasize that lub, glb and limits depend on  fundamental properties of $\Bbb R$ that in turn depend on its definition.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can show here by using:
$$ \frac{8n}{3n+1} = \frac{8}{3+ 1/n}$$

1. This is always smaller than $\frac{8}{3}$.
2. The sequence is strictly increasing
3. $\frac{8}{3+ \frac{1}{n+1}}$ is closer to $\frac{8}{3}$ than $\frac{8}{3+ \frac{1}{n}}$

This still doesn't prove that there is no number $x<\frac{8}{3}$ that the sequence is converging towards. So, if you can show that for all $x<\frac{8}{3}$, there is an n such that $x<\frac{8}{3+ \frac{1}{n+k}}$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, you have solved the problem.